# Return the result of $.get returns nothing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function which will return a JSON back. When checking the returned data in the calling function it was found to be undefined.

Only thing I can think of is ajax is async and it didn't wait for the data to be returned. Cuz that could be the only reason why the second alert box got triggered before the first alert.

```
$.get( '/search/s/g/' , { 'q' : query } , function(data) {
    var result = $.parseJSON(data);
    if ( result.length < 10 ) { 
        data2 = extendSearch(query);
        alert("second"); // This got triggered first.
    }
    populateSearchResult(result);
});

function extendSearch(q) {
    $.get('/search/s/f/', { 'q': q }, function(data) { 
         alert("first"); // This got triggered as the second alert box
         return data;
    });
}
```

Now how do i solve this?

Comment: ***Do not*** use `data2` outside of the `$.get` complete callback. the same goes for `data` in `extendSearch`

Comment: The **A** in Ajax. *sigh*

Comment: `data2 = extendSearch(query);` - `extendSearch` function will return you `null` as it is an asynchronous call. Read this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call for more information.

Comment: @Praveen [Ajax is also acceptable.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)). The point is you've completely neglected the fact that there's that **A** at the beginning.

Comment: @DaveNewton Anyways thats not the issue here... just let it go man...

Comment: @Praveen that actually is the issue. You're writing your code as if ajax were synchronous, but it's actually **A** synchronous. that's the point Dave is making.

Comment: @KevinB I knew that, and I have mentioned it in my post, just wanted a solution to it.

Comment: The solution is to re-think how you write your code... Use callbacks. There's at least a half dozen different ways you could write/organize your code to work asynchronously.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/NLMvx/

Comment: thanks adeneo, i was looking for something like that

Answer (score 1):

Don't return data, In `expandSearch` do what you need to do inside the success callback.

```
function expandSearch(q) {
    $.get('/search/s/f/', { 'q': q }, function(data) { 
         alert("first"); // This got triggered as the second alert box
         // do something with the data here
         // modify dom or w/e
    });
}
```

Comment: there is no way i can use the data outside the call back?

Comment: @Praveen well, there is a way, but it's bad programming.

Comment: @Praveen *It's **asynchronous**. The call returns before the request has completed. Use deferreds or something.